# Did Barack Obama receive 108% of the vote in one Ohio county?

Tags: politics, barack-obama, democracy

["Recount the election!"](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/recount-election/ZQmy0Mlv) is the 4th most popular petition at whitehouse.gov. It has 69,588 signatures (as of Jan 30, 2012).

As justification for the petition, the creator writes:

> In one county alone in Ohio, which was a battleground state, President Obama received 106,258 votes...but there were only 98,213 eligible voters. It's not humanly possible to get 108% of the vote!

Is this claim true?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13628/was-there-100-turn-out-and-100-obama-support-in-cuyahoga-county-in-2012-presid

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Politifact Ohio](http://www.politifact.com/ohio/statements/2012/nov/19/we-people-petition/online-petition-claims-obama-got-more-votes-one-co/) claims that the 106,258 was the amount of registered voters

> The posting's count of registered voters, 106,258, **matches a Plain Dealer tally of Sept. 17**. The latest number of registered voters in Wood County is 108,014, Board of Elections director Terry Burton told PolitiFact Ohio.
>
> Of those, only 80,433 are active voters, he said -- "and the difference between those numbers is the inactive voters."

Whereas the Obama votes were much lower:

> Wood County's total on Nov. 6 was 62,338 votes, he said, for a turnout of about 57 percent of registered voters.
>
> Obama's total in Wood County -- 31,596 votes, or about 51 percent of those cast -- was lower than his 2008 tally, according election night totals from the secretary of state. Mitt Romney received 28,997 votes, or about 47 percent -- less than John McCain's 2008 total.

I didn't double check their #s from primary sources, caveat emptor.

Comment: Even if the claim were true, one would need to be aware of voting regulations.  If a county recently did a voter roll "purge," and same-day registration was legal, a vote count could easily exceed the count of registered voters going into the election.